# How to put local storage data into a table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have data stored in local storage and so I'm trying to call ca function that will display that data. However, I am able to see the data but it does not show in the table. If someone can tell me how to modify my code so that the data is shown in the table in its applied cell than that would be great. 
Here's my Javascript:

```
function call() {
'use strict';
var get, create, text, i;
get = localStorage.getItem("A");//retrieves announcements from local storage 
create = JSON.parse(get);

text = "";
for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) { //displays multiple announcements
    text += "<td>" + create[i].username;//displaysname
    text += "<td>" + create[i].club;//displaysclub
    text += "<td>" + create[i].category;//displayscategory
    text += "<td>" + create[i].grade;//displaysgrade
    text += "<td>" + create[i].gender;//displaysgender
    text += "<td>" + create[i].Time;//displaystime
    text += "<td>" + create[i].detail + "<tr>";
}
document.getElementById("cool").innerHTML = text;

}
```

Here's my html page where the table is created:

```
 <title>Homepage Announcements</title>
    </head>
         <fieldset display:inline-block>
    <legend class="legend">
      Announcement Creator</legend>  

        <body>
 <div class="button">
     <button value="call" value="Display Announcements" onclick="call()">Display Announcements</button></div>


    <style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

th {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
</style>
<thead>
<table>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="head">Username</th>
                    <th class="head">Club</th>
                    <th class="head">Category</th>
                    <th class="head">Grade</th>
                    <th class="head">Gender</th>
                    <th class="head">Time</th>
                    <th class="head">Detail</th>
                  </tr>


</table>
     </thead>
<p id="cool"></p>
```

THIS IS THE JSON part:

```
var index = 0;
var announcement = [];
function rtdata() {
    'use strict';
    window.alert("Your announcement has been posted!");
    announcement[index] = {
        username : document.getElementById("username").value,
        club : document.getElementById("club").value,
        category : document.getElementById("category").value,
        grade : document.getElementById("grade").value,
        gender : document.getElementById("gender").value,
        time : document.getElementById("time").value,
        details : document.getElementById("details").value
    };
    index = index + 1;
    localStorage.setItem("A", JSON.stringify(announcement));
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("cool")` is not the table. You should also close your `<td>` and `<tr>` tags in the generated HTML and use a `<tbody>` to make sure it’s working across all browsers. `<thead>`s belong _inside_ the `<table>`, not outside it. There can’t be any HTML between `<head>` and `<body>`. `display:inline-block` is not a valid attribute. There are so many things wrong with your HTML… please use an HTML validator.

Comment: Please **improve** your formatting and **divide** the code into a JavaScript, CSS and a HTML part!

Comment: @Cutie Pie Can you provide an example JSON please that we can use for testing.

Comment: @Xufox document.getElementById("cool") is what displays the data. WIthout it the data wont show up at all. And I've tried the other suggestions that u've said in ur post however nothing has been fixed.

Comment: @CutiePie - nope. `document.getElementById("cool")` is how you get a reference to the element with the id of `cool`. In contrast, `document.getElementById("cool").innerHTML = text;` is how you're setting the innerHTML of the last `p` element in your shown HTML. As XuFox said, the element with the id of cool is not a table, but is a paragraph.

Comment: So you have an `<tr>` after the elements??

Comment: @enhzflep so would instead of a paragraph, I would have to adjust id so that it goes with the table?

Comment: @CutiePie - that's what I'd do. I'd approach it in much the same manner as akazemis did (though there are even shorter, better answers) I'll throw something together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your HTML to this :

```
<table>
<thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="head">Username</th>
                    <th class="head">Club</th>
                    <th class="head">Category</th>
                    <th class="head">Grade</th>
                    <th class="head">Gender</th>
                    <th class="head">Time</th>
                    <th class="head">Detail</th>
                  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="cool">
</tbody>

</table>
```

And you javascript to this :

```
for (i = 0; i < create.length; i++) { //displays multiple announcements
    text += "<tr>";
    text += "<td>" + create[i].username+ "</td>";//displaysname
    text += "<td>" + create[i].club+ "</td>";//displaysclub
    text += "<td>" + create[i].category+ "</td>";//displayscategory
    text += "<td>" + create[i].grade+ "</td>";//displaysgrade
    text += "<td>" + create[i].gender+ "</td>";//displaysgender
    text += "<td>" + create[i].Time+ "</td>";//displaystime
    text += "<td>" + create[i].detail+ "</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: @ akazemis this works thank you so much! The only problem is that for the last two column, time and detail, the data does not display and instead it displays undefined. could htere be a problem in the javascript?

Comment: My pleasure! it seems to be a field name typo. maybe you need to rename create[i].Time to create[i].time and create[i].detail to details. Check your JSON data or copy it here if you can.

Comment: Ive added the JSON part above. And I got time to work, but details colum still says undefined for every input data displayed. Is it because it's a textareawhile the rest were selects and inputs?

Comment: Cool, so as I guessed before it was just a typo, so just replace the create[i].Time with create[i].time and  create[i].detail with create[i].details to make it consistent with the JSON object.

Comment: Nevermind, it works now, i kept on writing the wrong spelling i realized. Thank you so much for ur help!

Answer (score 0):

I hate string concatenation for the construction of HTML, so tend to avoid it like the plague. I also avoid using `.length` in a loop's terminating condition, because doing this will cause the `.length` member to be called for each iteration of the loop. The better alternative is to grab a copy of the value once before the loop and re-use it.

For what it's worth, you can actually iterate over the properties of an object without even knowing their names. This means you can loop over both the rows AND the columns - this avoids typos when entering member field names, it means you can avoid hard-coding the header of the table and keeps your code even smaller and neater. (I dont use the technique often)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}
///////////////////////////////////
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded()
{
    displayData();
}

function newTd(newContent)
{
    var result = newEl('td');
    result.innerHTML = newContent;
    return result;
}

function displayData()
{
    var jsonData = [
                        {
                            username: 'enhzflep',
                            club: 'no',
                            category: 'n/a',
                            grade: '10',
                            gender: 'neutral',
                            Time: 'yes',
                            detail: 'no'
                        },
                        {
                            username: 'Cutie Pie',
                            club: 'programming',
                            category: 'special interest',
                            grade: 'A',
                            gender: 'unknown',
                            Time: 'yes',
                            detail: 'no'
                        }
                    ];

    var nItems = jsonData.length;
    for (var i=0; i<nItems; i++)
    {
        var tr = newEl('tr');
        tr.appendChild( newTd(jsonData[i].username) );
        tr.appendChild( newTd(jsonData[i].club) );
        tr.appendChild( newTd(jsonData[i].category) );
        tr.appendChild( newTd(jsonData[i].grade) );
        tr.appendChild( newTd(jsonData[i].gender) );
        tr.appendChild( newTd(jsonData[i].Time) );
        tr.appendChild( newTd(jsonData[i].detail) );
        byId('insertHere').appendChild(tr);
    }
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="head">Username</th>
                <th class="head">Club</th>
                <th class="head">Category</th>
                <th class="head">Grade</th>
                <th class="head">Gender</th>
                <th class="head">Time</th>
                <th class="head">Detail</th>
            </tr>
        <thead>
        <tbody id='insertHere'></tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. I just wanted to fix the main problem in code. this approach is definitely better.

Comment: @akazemis -your approach is still perfectly functional and deserves the vote I gave it, I think. Each provides a stepping-stone to something new.

Comment: @enhzflep thank you for ur answer. I have tried ur way too and it does seem to work! Although, i might as well just keep it to what i had before since its part of the requirement for my project. Thank you for ur effort once again!

Comment: @CutiePie - you're welcome. Its purpose was not to answer your (already accepted) question so much as to provide a few extra tips and something to consider for future use. :)